# Does Deepstream keep track of the entire document in RethinkDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deepstream.io

I know that Deepstream keeps track of everything in the _d-part of the document in the database and I need to use Deepstream to change anything in there which is fine. I'm wondering if I'm not allowed to change any values outside _d?

My database schema looks like this:

```
{
  _d: {Deepstream stuff},
  _v: 1,
  registrationCode: 'random string'
}
```

Now, when a user registers I will remove the `registrationCode` and replace it with `password`, like this:

```
{
  _d: {Deepstream stuff},
  _v: 1,
  password: 'pw string'
}
```

However, when Deepstream logs in on my client it will replace `password` with `registrationCode` again with the same value. My guess is that it caches the entire document, and not just whats inside `_d`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. I appreciate that its a bit tedious, but in order to introduce private information like passwords etc with a record, I'd much rather create a second record, e.g. -private. This way this record can be permissioned individually and will create an individual document in RethinkDB

Comment: Thanks for the answer =)
Maybe you should add this to the website somewhere